# angular2 multiple http calls promises observables

Tags: angular, http

```
let observable1 = http.get('api1').subscribe(r1 => {//display r1});
let observable2 = http.get('api2').subscribe(r1 => {//display r1});
```

How to hide loading mask when both APIs have responded?

Problem facing -

If I try to write

```
Observable.forkJoin([observable1, observable2]).subscribe(res => {
//hide loading msk
})
```

forkJoin calls both services again.

Also, with forkJoin, I can not display data of the service whichever responds first as soon it is available until both services respond.

Comment: Fallow the given url :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-loading

Comment: use 2 flags for each request. when you receive the response turn each flag to false in the respective call. On loading mask put condition that it should be displayed only when both flags are true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but In angularJS, there was no need of flags, with `$q.all(promises).then(res => {//hide loader})` it used to work. Also, if we use flags, it will become tedious to manage all flags, if more than 2 or several more calls are included on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
Observable.forkJoin(
    apiCall1(params),
    apiCall2(params),
    apiCall3(params)
).subscribe((responses) => {
    console.log('response for apiCall1 :', responses[0])
    console.log('response for apiCall2 :', responses[1])
    console.log('response for apiCall3 :', responses[2])
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give a try.